# Uncaught TypeError: MyView is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have created my-view.js file as follows:

```
(function (Backbone) {
  var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'card my-card',
    template: $('#my-template').html(),
    initialize: function(options) {
      this.render()
    },
    render: function() {
      var html = _.template(this.template);
      this.$el.html(html);
      return this;
    }
  });

  app.modules.MyView = MyView;
}(window.Backbone);
```

In app-controller.js, I have wrote as follows:

```
(function (Backbone) {
  var MyDayCardView = app.modules.MyView,  
  var AppController = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){  
      var self = this;
    },
    appStart: function() {
      this.MyDayCardView = new MyDayCardView();
      self.$el.append(this.MyDayCardView.el);
    }
  });

  app.controllers.AppController = new AppController();    
}(window.Backbone);
```

Then I got error:

> Uncaught TypeError: MyView is not a function
>       Backbone.View.extend.appStart @ app-controller.js:

Where I did wrong?

Comment: This code can't possibly run in your browser, it's riddled with errors.

Comment: Are you sure my-view.js is executed before controller.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax issues , see the below code

```
var app={};
app.modules={};
app.controllers={};
// Add your javascript here
(function (Backbone) {
  var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'card my-card',
    template: $('#my-template').html(),
    initialize: function(options) {
      this.render()
    },
    render: function() {
      var html = _.template(this.template);
      this.$el.html(html);
      return this;
    }
  });

  app.modules.MyView = MyView;
}(window.Backbone));

(function (Backbone) {
  var MyDayCardView = app.modules.MyView,  
   AppController = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){  
      var self = this;
    },
    appStart: function() {
      this.MyDayCardView = new MyDayCardView();
      self.$el.append(this.MyDayCardView.el);
    }
  });

  app.controllers.AppController = new AppController();    
}(window.Backbone));
```